# For each loop iterates the first empty element of a collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, iteration

I have added 2 elements to a vb .net collection. When debugging I can see the .count = 2.

If a watch for the elements inside the collection I see as usually a first empty element in the zero index and then the two elements that I have added.

[image]

The problem is that when I iterate the collection with a For Each Next loop, the empty element is iterated and the last element is not.

This is how the structure is declared

```
Structure bstCategory
    Dim categoryCode As String
    Dim categoryVersion As String
End Structure
```

This is how the collection is populated

```
 With ci.tItem.information
    .categories = New Collection
    Dim additionalClassification As bstCategory
    additionalClassification.categoryCode = "1"
    additionalClassification.categoryVersion = "A"
    .categories.Add(additionalClassification)
    additionalClassification.categoryCode = "2"
    additionalClassification.categoryVersion = "B"
    .categories.Add(additionalClassification)
End With
```

This is how the collection is iterated

```
For Each category As bstCategory In ci.tItem.information.categories
        ValidateCategory(categorycode)
Next
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `        Dim names As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()
        names.Add("John")
        names.Add(2)

        For Each x In names
            Console.WriteLine(x)
        Next` works for me. Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Can you post your code for `bstCategory`? If its a class you created, check the code

Comment: I have restarted VS, but the problem is still there.

Comment: bstCategory is an structure type:      Structure bstCategory
        Dim categoryCode As String
        Dim categoryVersion As String
    End Structure

Comment: it would help if you showed a: how `categories` is created, and b: how `categories` is populated.

Comment: It is important to see the code you used to add elements to the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your issue, it works fine for me using vb.net in vs2010 target .net 2.0

Here what I tried based on your code:

```
Module Module1

    Structure bstCategory
        Dim Code As String
        Dim Version As String
    End Structure

    Sub Main()

        Dim categories As New Collection()
        Dim c As New bstCategory
        c.Code = "1"
        c.Version = "1"
        categories.Add(c)
        categories.Add(c)

        For Each category As bstCategory In categories
            Console.WriteLine(category.Code)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

If For Each is giving you that strange behavior, you can change it to use a For instead.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To categories.Count
   Console.WriteLine(categories(i).Code)
Next
```

Anyway, it is very strange what you are facing and what I suggest is to look for the index 0 text in Google. I did it and there are some pages talking about that so your answer may be there.

Google for: "empty placeholder to adjust for 1-based array"

Hope that helps!

here is a picture showing the 3 values in the collection from 0 to 2, however, when iterated it only enters twice printing out 1 twice.

[image]

Comment: If I use a for instead of a For Each it works, but I have used lots of For each loops through the same code and it worries me if has been working wrongly for a long time